# Trigger on insert/update to table if one combination exists

Tags: mysql, triggers

A table has three rows: analysisId (int, AUTO_INCREMENT), dataId (int, foreign key from another tables), first_attempt (bool)
I have a trigger which is supposed to be a constraint that checks the entire table, if there is a "dataId" with first_attempt as 1, 
then you cannot add another dataId with the first_attempt being '1'. However, it should accept any number of entries if dataId is used before, and first_attempt is 0.

I've written a trigger, but mysql keeps throwing a syntax error and I'm not sure what's the problem.

Here are my tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    dataId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    machine char(20) NOT NULL,
    run char(25) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (dataId)
) ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE table2 (
    analysisId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dataId int NOT NULL,
    first_attempt boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY (analysisId),
    FOREIGN KEY (dataId)
        REFERENCES seq_data(dataId)
        ON DELETE CASCADE   
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Populate data with dummy values:

```sql
INSERT INTO `table1` (`dataId`, `machine`, `run`) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'mac1', 'first_run');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`analysisId`, `dataId`, `clinical`) VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 1);
```

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `clinical_gatekeeper`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        IF (NEW.dataId = table2.dataId ) THEN
            SELECT CONCAT(NEW.dataId, " has already completed one successful run!") INTO @error_text;
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE "45000" SET message_text = @error_text; 
        END IF; 
    END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Personally, I think I have a problem with `IF (NEW.dataId = table2.dataId ) THEN` Because if I substitute table2.dataId for 1 it works!

Comment: Please provide table definitions, and some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `table2`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE dataId = NEW.dataId AND clinical = NEW.clinical AND clinical = 1) THEN
            SELECT CONCAT(NEW.dataId, " has already completed one successful run!") INTO @error_text;
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE "45000" SET message_text = @error_text; 
        END IF; 
    END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```